# Maintain LazyColumn scroll position after re-composition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I'm building a composable screen, say `PostScreen` where multiple posts are shown in `GridView` and when user click on any of them, I'll navigate to `DetailScreen` where posts are shown in larger box with multiple buttons associated (like, comment).
My logic is, when user click on any post in `PostScreen`, use an index from `PostScreen` to scroll to that index in `DetailScreen`. Issue is, when user click on any post (and arrive to `DetailScreen`), then move up (or down) wards and then click on action (for example, like a post), a coroutine operation is launched but index is getting reset and `DetailScreen` scroll to original index instead of staying at liked post. How would i resolve this? (I know about `rememberLazyListState()`)

```
@Composable
fun DetailScreen(
    viewModel: MyViewModel,
    index: Int? // index is coming from navGraph
) {
    val postIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(index) }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val posts = remember(viewModel) { viewModel.posts }.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = { MyTopBar() }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        JustNestedScreen(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
            posts = posts,
            onLike = { post ->
                // This is causing index to reset, maybe due to re-composition
                scope.launch {
                    viewModel.toggleLike(
                        postId = post.postId,
                        isLiked = post.isLiked
                    )
                }
            },
            indexToScroll = postIndex
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun JustNestedScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    posts: LazyPagingItems<ExplorePost>,
    onLike: (Post) -> Unit,
    indexToScroll: Int? = null
) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background),
        state = listState
    ) {
        items(posts) { post ->
            post?.let {
                // Display image in box and some buttons
                FeedPostItem(
                    post = it,
                    onLike = onLike,
                )
            }
        }

        indexToScroll?.let { index ->
                scope.launch {
                    listState.scrollToItem(index = index)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You commented that index is coming from navGraph. How do you get the index from the navGraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LaunchedEffect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect). `LaunchedEffect`'s block is only run the first time and then every time keys are changed. If you only want to run it once, use `Unit` or `listState` as a key:

```
LaunchedEffect(listState) {
    indexToScroll?.let { index ->
        listState.scrollToItem(index = index)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'v used `LaunchedEffect` multiple times in same project, but somehow missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Compose's LazyListState takes the initial item index and scroll offset as parameters. Since it is remembered it will be kept through recomposition.

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState(
    initialFirstVisibleItemIndex = index,
    initialFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset = offset,
)
```